# How do I implement methods using Method Reference inside a map or flatMap

Tags: java, spring-boot, webclient

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54127397/3672700) so I could understand better how to deal with asynchronous requests, and even though I understand what he is doing here:

```
.map(processor::responseToDatabaseEntity) // Create a persistable entity from the response
.map(priceRepository::save)               // Save the entity to the database
```

I have no idea how these two methods would be implemented. Assuming this very simple code:

```
public Mono<Response> postMethod(String id, Person json) {
        return webClient.post().uri(id).body(Mono.just(json), Person.class).retrieve().bodyToMono(Response.class);
}
```

And the Response Class, something like:

```
public class Response implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4101206629695985431L;
    
    public String statusCode;
    public Date date;
    public PersonInfo data;
```

I assume the `responseToDatabaseEntity` method would be some sort of transformation from the Response to PersonInfoDTO to the database, and the `save` would insert into it. But how could I implement something like that using Method Reference(::) that would work inside the `.map()` so I can subscribe() after is what I don't understand.

EDIT:
Adding the progress I had but adapting more or less to the example I gave with Person class:

```
public Mono<Object> postPerson(String id, Person json) {
        return webClient.post().uri(id).body(Mono.just(json), Person.class).retrieve().bodyToMono(Response.class).map( c -> {
            List<PersonDTO> list = new ArrayList<PersonDTO>();
            c.data.getRoles().forEach((r) -> {
                PersonDTO dto = new PersonDTO(c.data.getOof(), "something", c.data.getFoo(), r);
                list.add(dto);
            });
            return list;        
        }).map(personController::savePerson).subscribe(); //what I wanted to do
    }
```

If I do this:

```
    });
    return list;        
}).map(l -> {
        l.
    });
```

`l` contains a list of PersonDTO, and if I do this:

```
  .map(l -> {
        l.forEach( f -> {
            f.
        });
    });
```

`f` contains a Person.

How should I implement the method to send the entire list to insert in the method or send one person by person to `save`. I can't use a static method like `PersonController::savePerson` because:

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private final PersonInterface personRepository;

    public PersonController(PersonInterface personRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }
```

`personRepository` cannot be `static`.

EDIT2: Have also tried this, does not work:

```
public List<PersonDTO> savePerson(List<PersonDTO> list) {
        list.forEach(dto -> {
            personRepository.save(dto);
        });
        return list;
}
```

Comment: Can you please specify what you don't understand in more detail?
Your assumption is correct.
You can write a map method that will return an object, then finally call subscribe().
For method reference - this should be helpful - https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-references

Comment: I've edited the comment with more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can write `responseToDatabaseEntity` method in any class - you can create a processor or a dedicated transformer which is capable of transforming [Entity to Data Objects](https://www.amitph.com/spring-entity-to-dto/) and Vice Versa.

The Map function which is getting called upon a Stream of Response instances will accept reference to any method that takes a single argument of Response instance and returns an object of any type.

So, for example I have created a dedicated transformer

```
public class EntityDtoTransformer{
    public EntityObject responseToDatabaseEntity(Response response){
        ...
        ...
        return entity;  
    }
}
```

You can refer this method in Map funnction like:

```
entityDtoTransformerInstance::responseToDatabaseEntity
```

Also, you can make this method *static* and then use it in the map function as

```
EntityDtoTransformer::responseToDatabaseEntity
```

If your transformer method is part of the response class your can

```
.map(res -> response.responseToDatabaseEntity)
```

or in shorted form

```
.map(Response::responseToDatabaseEntity)
```

Comment: I have tried this, the static approach works but I don't want this option, however the first one does not, it simply says `entityDtoTransformerInstance` cannot be resolved. Using my example, I have created this in the `Response` class:

`public ResponseDTO responseToDatabaseEntity(Response response){
   ResponseDTO a = new ResponseDTO(response);
                 return a;
 }`

and added `.map(responseInstance::responseToDatabaseEntity);`

responseInstance cannot be resolved.

Comment: have covered your scenario in the answer

Comment: Yeah I was able to do something like that but I wrote all the operations inside the .map instead of creating a function. However the problem now, is implementing the `save` method as in the original post I linked, since the :

`private final PersonInterface personRepository;

public PersonController(PersonInterface personRepository) {
    this.personRepository = personRepository;
}`

is in a different class called `PersonController`. I can't use the static approach here because personRepository cannot be static. I'll edit my comment with more details but adapted to Person example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help, I have edited my comment.